# CouchDB exclude from view based on list of regex expressions

Tags: regex, view, couchdb

Whats the best approach for excluding documents from a view based on a list of regex expressions. For example I want to exclude anything where doc.issue.name contains a value that matches a list of regex expressions.

e.g. exclusion list: [/foo/, /bar/]

```
{
"_id": "1",
"issue": {
    "name": "foo"
}

{
"_id": "2",
"issue": {
    "name": "bar"
}

{
"_id": "3",
"issue": {
    "name": "fred"
}
```

So based on the documents above, just return the document where doc.issue.name = "fred"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so to answer my own question here in case anybody else needs to do this type of thing!

Based on the following documents:

```
{
"_id": "1",
"issue": {
"name": "foo"
}

{
"_id": "2",
 "issue": {
"name": "bar"
}

{
"_id": "3",
"issue": {
"name": "fred"
}
```

This map function:

```
function(doc) {
 var reg_exps = [/foo/g, /bar/g];
 for (r in reg_exps){
   if (doc.name.match(reg_exps[r])){
     return;
   }
 }
 emit(doc.name, 1);
}
```

Will only return the document with the name of "fred"